Definition of $O_X(P)$ and $O_X(-P)$
I'm having problems understanding the definitions of the title. Let $(X,O_X)$ a curve and P a closed point of $X$. What are $O_X(P)$ and $O_X(-P)$?.
For example, I know that $O_X(-P)$ arises from the exact sequence
\begin{equation*}
0 \longrightarrow O_X(-P) \longrightarrow O_X\longrightarrow i_* O_P \longrightarrow 0.
\end{equation*}
Then,
\begin{equation}
O_X(-P)(U)=\left\lbrace\begin{array}{c} O_X(U) ~~if~P \notin U\\\\
"O_X(U)~~mod~{m_P}"~~if~P \in U \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
where the expression "$O_X(U)~~mod~m_P$" refers to sections in $f \in O_X(U)$ reduced by the maximal ideal associated to P, $m_P$ (ie, its image under the map $O_X(U) \longrightarrow K(P)$ the residual field of $P$). All of this in a purely-algebraic view.

Is this definition of $O_X(-P)$ right?
Is there a definition of $O_X(P)$ through exact short sequences?
Is there a generalization of this sheaves in this sense: what $O_X(nP)$ and $O_X(-nP)$ would be?
Thinking in elements of $O_X(U)$ as "functions", How can I think the elements of $O_X(P)$ and $O_X(-P)$ related to "poles an zeros in $P$"?

I'm really confused at this, so I would like some help to clarify my ideas, so maybe somethings written here may have no sense.
Thanks in advance!

I would probably not write the definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(-P)$ as you have. Perhaps a better way to write it is: when $U\ni P$, $\mathcal{O}_X(-P)(U)$ is the subgroup of $\mathcal{O}_X(U)$ consisting of sections that vanish at $P$. This is equivalent in this case to taking the set of $f\in \mathcal{O}_X(U)$ such that $f_P$ is in the maximal ideal of $\mathcal{O}_{X,P}$.
The question of whether or not there is a definition of $\mathcal{O}_X(P)$ through short exact sequences is somewhat vague. I would define it as the dual to $\mathcal{O}_X(-P)$. Then, $\mathcal{O}_{X}(nP) = \mathcal{O}_X(P)^{\otimes n}$.
We already addressed how to regard $\mathcal{O}_X(-P)$ as a subsheaf of $\mathcal{O}_X$, hence as regular functions on $X$ with a property. In the case of $\mathcal{O}_X(P)$, you can define $\mathcal{O}_X(P)$ as the subsheaf of the (constant) sheaf of rational functions on $X$ such that: if $P\in U$ then $\mathcal{O}_X(P)(U)$ consists of rational functions on $U$ that have at most a pole of order $1$ at $P$ and no other poles. If $P\not\in U$, then $\mathcal{O}_X(P)(U)  =\mathcal{O}_X(U)$.
I think a good treatment of this is in Miranda's book on algebraic curves and Riemann surfaces, though it is also in Hartshorne.

Thank you very much for your answer. I have another question related to $O_X(-nP)$. As  $O_X(-P)$ can be thought like the sections such that $f_P $ in the maximal ideal of $O_{X,P}$, can I think elements in $O_X(-nP)$ as sections such that $f_P^n$ is in the maxima ideal of $O_{X,P}$?

Other way; $f_P$ is in $\mathfrak{m}_P^n$, which just means that they vanish to order $n$ at $P$.

Makes a lot of sense!
